# Данные не приходят в Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При отправки в Firebase отправляются только фото, без текста и базы данных так таковой.
Делаю по гайду, но не понимаю, в чем причина.
Вероятно, в гайде, используется устаревший метод `getDownloadUrl()`, но фото от этого не страдает. Я не понимаю в сем причина, так как я новичек еще в этой сфере, пожалуйста, помогите, я уже не понимаю, что мне делать. Что бы, что-то понять, посмотрите в Мейн

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private Button mButtonUpload;
    private TextView mTextViewShowUploads;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Uri mImageUri;

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_im);
        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mTextViewShowUploads = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show);
        mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    uploadFile();
                }
            }
        });

        mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Upload

```
public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload(){
    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {

        this.mName = name;
        this.mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_choose_im"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_choose_im"
        android:hint="Enter"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_upload"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Upload" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_upload"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Show"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ссылку на гайд дай.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPfQN-Sfnjw&ab_channel=CodinginFlow

Comment: а addOnFailureListener срабатывает? Там должен быть тост с ошибкой у тебя

Comment: ошибок как раз нет((

Comment: Тогда дебажся - глянь что mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads"); mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads"); - после инициализации не null, и проверь что у тебя  mImageUri не null - может просто тебе uri не приходит

Comment: проверил( 
везде не 0((

Comment: Ок, можно еще проверить rules в базах, что write = true, и ничего там нет лишнего. И тогда надо смотреть колбэки mUploadTask - должно же хоть что нибудь вызыватся. Еще у таски должен быть колбэк addOnCompleteListener - повешай и его.

Comment: Михаил, спасибо, что потратили на меня время. Я решил создать новый файл на основе похожего и все заработало. Спасибо, что вы есть❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам полностью рабочий пример

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

import tj.good.realestate.R;
import tj.good.realestate.helpers.imagepicker.ImagePicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // initialize firebase DatabaseReference
    private DatabaseReference databaseRef;
    // initialize firebase StorageReference
    private StorageReference reference;

    private Uri userImageUri = null;
    private Button uploadBr;
    private Button selectImage;
    ImageView imageView;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        uploadBr = findViewById(R.id.uploadBr);
        selectImage = findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        // initialize firebase FirebaseStorage
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        reference = storage.getReference();

        
        selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        uploadBr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveDateToDB();
            }
        });

    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    }

    // get result added image
    final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), (ActivityResult result) -> {
                if (result.getData() != null && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Use the uri to load the image
                    userImageUri = result.getData().getData();

                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(userImageUri)
                            .into(imageView);

                } else if (result.getResultCode() == ImagePicker.RESULT_ERROR) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }); // end ActivityResultLauncher


    private void saveDateToDB() {
        // show progressBar if you have

        // get timestamp
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HashMap<String, Object> date = new HashMap<>();
        date.put("userId", timestamp);
        date.put("userName", "Blablabla");
        date.put("userPhone", "+992930033232");
        date.put("userCountry", "Tajikistan");
        date.put("timestamp", timestamp);

        // load image
        if (userImageUri != null) {
            // create name for file
            String fileName = timestamp + "." + getExtensionType(userImageUri);
            date.put("userImageLink", fileName);
            uploadUrlFileToFirebaseStorage(userImageUri, fileName);
        }

        databaseRef.child("Users").child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).setValue(date)
                .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                    // hide progressBar

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Данные успешно сохранено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                  finish();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // hide progress bar
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });

    }

    // load uri file to firebase storage
    private void uploadUrlFileToFirebaseStorage(Uri uri, String fileName) {

        StorageReference path = reference.child("Users").child("Image").child(fileName);

        path.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    // successful
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            // get error message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    private String getExtensionType(Uri uri) {
        String extension;
        //Check uri format to avoid null
        if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            //If scheme is a content
            final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(this.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        } else {
            //If scheme is a File
            //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
            extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());
        }
        return extension;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема с методом `getFileExtension` попробуйте заменить метод на этот:

```
public String getFileExtension(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;
    //Check uri format to avoid null
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        //If scheme is a content
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        //If scheme is a File
        //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());
    }
    return extension;
}
```

затем замените `getFileExtension(mImageUri)` на `getFileExtension(this, mImageUri)`

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались на помощь. К сожалению, нечего не изменилось(
По прежнему пустая панель. Может еще что-то есть?(

Comment: Я изменил сообщение и добавил скрин. Может, это поможет